# As suddenly as is the same as as soon as?

Tags: word-usage, tense

> The fog lifts as suddenly as it had descended.

The sentence has been taken from a story. I think the verb "lifts" is incorrect. And I'd like to know whether "as suddenly as" is the same as "as soon as".

Comment: ***NO!*** - *as soon as* means the fog lifted *immediately after* it descended, whereas *as suddenly as* means the fog both descended and lifted very rapidly (but it may have hung around for *days* in between coming and going).

Answer (score 1):

The verb "lift" is often associated with "fog" - this is not an error. Example:

> "I think we should wait until the fog *lifts* before we leave on our trip."

The word "suddenly" is *not* the same as "as soon as."

"**Suddenly**" implies that it was unexpected, or that it happened very quickly (meaning that once it started lifting, it did not take long to disappear). It's possible that the fog came down, stayed for a while, and then left later (but very quickly).

"**As soon as**" means that when the fog settled or descended, it immediately lifted. This means that it the fog did not stay at all. It came down, and promptly left.

---

**Note:** While the sentence is grammatically correct, I think it would *sound* more natural to native speakers if the two verbs shared the same tense, i.e.

> "The fog *lifted* as suddenly as it had *descended*."

or

> "The fog *lifts* as suddenly as it *descends*."

Comment: There is no need for the verb tenses to agree here. These are two separate clauses being linked together by a comparison.

Comment: @Era No matter how hard I try to put that sentence (as is) in context, it still doesn't _sound_ right to me. I can't imagine ever hearing someone say that. Could you give me an example where you would say that, using the same structure but different verbs with a different subject and comparison?

Comment: The reason it sounds odd to you is that it's much more common to say "the fog lifted". Imagine however that you're listening to someone tell a story. We were driving into the mountains and suddenly we can't see 2 feet in front of the car. We go about another 100 meters, and the fog lifts as suddenly as it descended. It descended in the past, but it's lifting right now.

Comment: @CaseyJamesGarland e.g. *"I will defeat you as easily as I defeated your father."*

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you for that explanation - that makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Era Your example doesn't follow the same tense structure - you used the future as opposed to the present. If I used your example with the OP's sentence structure, it would read (let's use "he" to keep the 3rd person singular) "He defeats you as easily as he defeated your father," which still sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @CaseyJamesGarland My point is only that there is no grammatical rule that the tenses must agree. Many grammatically correct sentences are nevertheless odd-sounding, but that's essentially a stylistic issue.

Comment: @Era I understand. That being said, I'll accept your edits - but I'll leave a note regarding why the sentence at least sounds odd and can be "improved" by keeping the tenses consistent.

Comment: Changing the tenses around changes the meaning and doesn't really fix how natural it might sound. Whether the tense combination sounds right really depends on the context. "The fog lifts as suddenly as it descends." makes no sense to me unless it's something like "In Harbor Town, the fog always lifts as suddenly as it descends." I think that you're getting hung up on the tenses because the example sentence is out of context. The clauses of a sentence do not have to describe things that occur at exactly the same time.

Comment: @ColleenV Precisely - because the sentence lacks any context whatsoever it's hard for me to make a proper suggestion. Anyway, I think the answer is sufficient for what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using *lift* with *fog* like this is quite common, and not a mistake. In this usage, *to lift* is intransitive and refers to the fog dissipating.

*As suddenly* means **at the same rate and equally unexpected**. This type of comparison can be used in abstract terms, e.g.

> He fired the gun as suddenly as a bolt of lightning.

This sentence doesn't imply that there was lightning present when the gun was fired. It's merely drawing a comparison between **how sudden** the gunshot was and **how sudden** a lightning strike is. (See the dictionary definition of *sudden* for more info about what that means.)

On the other hand, *as soon as* means **at the same time or immediately after**. It relates the times at which two events occurred.

> As soon as I took a bow, the audience erupted into applause.

So, in your example, what happened is that the fog suddenly descended, then, at an unspecified later time, the fog suddenly lifted.

Comment: According to you, I think you should write like the following: The fog lifts as suddenly as it descended.

Answer (score -3):

**'Lifts'** where means the fog disappears. Its often associated with fog and mist or other veils.

**'Suddenly'** refers more to a short length of time, as in quickly or unexpectedly.

**'As soon as'** refers to the single point in time of, eg:
`He ran inside as soon as the rain started.` means at the point in time where the rain started, he ran inside at the same time, or very shortly after